# Replace JobService() by Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, android-notifications, kotlin-coroutines, jobservice

Ther is a

```
@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
class SomeNotification : JobService() {
    
    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {        
        //..
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        //..
    }
}
```

**Can I use Coroutines here, instead of Jobservice?**

I also did not understood the JobService comment:

> This means that you **must** offload your execution logic to  *
> another thread/handler/{@link android.os.AsyncTask} of your choosing.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)

```
def work_version = "2.3.4"

// Kotlin + coroutines
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
```

and [`CoroutineWorker`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker):

```
class CoroutineDownloadWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
    val jobs = (0 until 100).map {
        async {
            downloadSynchronously("https://www.google.com")
        }
    }

    // awaitAll will throw an exception if a download fails, which CoroutineWorker will treat as a failure
    jobs.awaitAll()
    Result.success()
}


private suspend fun showNotification(progress: Int) {
    setForeground(
        ForegroundInfo(
            notificationId,
            NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext, channelId)
                .setContentTitle(appContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setProgress(100, progress, false)
                .setContentText(appContext.getString(R.string.content_text))
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(appContext, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .build()
        )
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Although WorkManager might be the alternative, its use-case is different than JobService mainly because of 15 mins schedule limit.